# display primary key related data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have table with the folowing columns:
row_id, customer_id, worker_id, vehicle_id, task_id, subcontractor_id.

I need to get the folowing data:
row_id, customer_name, worker_name, vehicle_name, task_serial, subcontractor_name

I can do this using simple inner joins for each table (Customers, Workers etc.) But each table is really huge (a lot of rows and each row has many fields), and I know that *_id (customer_id, worker_id, ..) is the primary key of its table.

Is there a way I can get this data and avoid many inner joins?

(maybe something with the foreign key, primary key or something like this..)

thanks

Comment: That's exactly what joins are for. What do you mean by huge?

Comment: like Kakao said, what you are describing is the way you have to do it...read up on joins here:  http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to use joins - and it is not bad at all.

If the *_id columns are indexed (and primary keys are ususally indexed) it doesn't matter that the join tables are huge as the query processor will use the index to find the correct rows in the join tables - and not do a full table scan. The "many columns" should also be no problem for your query processor...

So I think the query will look something like this:

```
SELECT a.row_id, customer_name, worker_name, vehicle_name, task_serial, subcontractor_name 
FROM my_table as a
INNER JOIN CUSOMER as b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
INNER JOIN WORKER as c ON a.worker_id = c.worker_id
...
```

Of course you can use Left koins as well.

Comment: I actually do left join because *_id can be null. Is this ok too?
I also know there is a way to store customer_name (for example) in the primary key. can you update your question with an answer of how doing that?

Comment: Of course you can use left joins. I updated my answer. But I don't understand your second question.. What do you mean by "store customer_name" in the primary key? Do you wish to define a primary key on the name? Why - since you have an ID?

Comment: I've read somewhere that there is an option to store additional data on the leavs of the tree created by the primary key.

Comment: Hm I've never heard about this. Your DBMS will create a tree for the index of the primary key (probably a b-tree). And of course it would be possible to store additional information to the leaves next to the link to the acutal data record. But this sounds like something your DBMS will automatically do (e.g. some parameters for optimization or so). 

Using joins is the common way for your problem. But you may read the manual pages of your DBMS. What do you use MySQL, MS SQLServer, ...?